# Trying to hide and show Flash video player with ExternalInterface

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create an overlay containing a flash player that is shown when a user clicks on a link. The div containing the player starts with `display:none` in CSS. Upon clicking, the div will be shown, and JS will use ExternalInterface to configure and start the player. The JS configures the player when it catches a "flash ready" event, which is fired by Flash on `ADDED_TO_STAGE`.

All this works, except that the ExternalInterface callbacks are never created. The JS and AS3 work fine if the player is shown upon page load, or is hidden with `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`. I am aware [that Flash will not be initialized with `display:none`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056589/loading-an-flv-in-facebox-with-jquery-for-ie7-and-ie8), and this works as expected: when the Flash is unhidden, it fires its events and correctly initializes everything else (eg. GUI, other internal stuff). The only thing that doesn't happen as expected is that my ExternalInterface callbacks are not added.

`ExternalInterface.available` is true. It's not a timing problem, because even after several minutes the callbacks are still not present. The strangest bit is that the flash is able to call JS, fires JS events fine, and the code to fire the events comes after the code to add the callbacks. There are no errors thrown by any of the AS3 code. I'm seeing this problem in both Chrome and Firefox.

FWIW, I'm coding the embed HTML directly instead of using SWFObject, due to some unusual requirements.

Has anyone run into this sort of problem with `display:none` and ExternalInterface?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, I've tried setting `wmode` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142030/how-to-use-display-none-and-block-for-a-flash-object). Didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post your code?  It could be an issue of events firing before DOM considerations, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with some details I glossed over, thinking they were unimportant (sorry!). The showing/hiding of the Flash video was being handled by FancyBox, which actually copies your hidden HTML into a new div and shows that div. This worked as such, and the newly minted player was able to initialize and fire events. However, it used `ExternalInterface.objectID` to reference itself, and due to FancyBox there were now two elements with the same ID in the DOM. Therefore, the events that were triggered like `$(#objectId).trigger(...)` had `.target` set to the original Flash player, which was still hidden, and therefore had not initialized, and did not have the callbacks I was looking for.

I solved this by putting the HTML for fancybox in an HTML script tag:

```
<script type="text/html" id="fancyBoxTargetId">[Flash player html]</script>
```

this prevented there from being two elements with the same ID in the DOM (good to do anyway), and allowed Flash to self-reference using `ExternalInterface.objectID`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with addCallBack before. What I ended up doing was having my Flash call an init() function in JS after it's loaded, then within that init, setting up and transferring variables.

Hopefully that helps!